# Google Earth Engine: K-mean clustering of population data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, clustering

I would like to cluster population data using k-means or weighted k-means and then display the clusters as various colours to help differentiate them. I can easily do this on python with a table as input, but find it more clunky for this application. I would use eather the 100m satelite data or the 25m FB human data.

```js
// Define the area of interest
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-180, -90, 180, 90]);

// Load the population data
var population = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop");

// Select the population data for a specific year
var year = 2020;
var populationData = population.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', year)).first().select('population').toInt();

// Convert the population image to a feature collection of points
var populationFC = populationData.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 1000,
  geometryType: 'point',
  eightConnected: true,
  labelProperty: 'population'
});

// Create a feature collection of random points
var numClusters = 5;
var points = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geometry, numClusters);

// Cluster the population data using k-means
var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(numClusters).train(populationFC);
var clusters = populationFC.cluster(clusterer);

// Define a palette for the clusters
var palette = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange'];

// Join the palette colors into a single string
var fillColor = palette.join(',');

// Set the style of the clusters and add to the map
var styledClusters = clusters.style({color: 'white', fillColor: fillColor, pointSize: 3});
Map.addLayer(styledClusters, {}, 'Population Clusters');

// Export the clusters as a GeoTIFF
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clusters,
  description: 'population_clusters',
  scale: 1000,
  region: geometry
});
```